# Add localization to entity

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

How to add `DisplayName` in another language version from code?

```
createCategoryCommand.Process(context, category.ParentCatalogId, category.Name, category.DisplayName, category.Description);
```

commands don't accept language parameter and I cannot find any other method for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to save category first and then provide localizations for it. Let's say you already have `Category categoryEntity`. You then need to do the following steps:

```
// getting localization entity for your category. it will automatically create new if there is no existing one
LocalizationEntity localizationEntity = await this.localizeEntityPropertyCommand.GetLocalizationEntity(context.CommerceContext, categoryEntity);

// preparing translations
List<Parameter> localizations = new List<Parameter>
                                    {
                                        new Parameter
                                            {
                                                Key = "en", Value = "Default Display Name"
                                            },
                                        new Parameter
                                            {
                                                Key = "fr-FR", Value = "French Display Name"
                                            }
                                    };

// adding localizations for DisplayName property
localizationEntity.AddOrUpdatePropertyValue("DisplayName", localizations);

// saving localization entity to database
await this.persistEntityPipeline.Run(new PersistEntityArgument(localizationEntity), context);

// this is needed if initial category didn't have LocalizedEntityComponent to link category with localization entity
if (!categoryEntity.HasComponent<LocalizedEntityComponent>())
{
    categoryEntity.SetComponent(new LocalizedEntityComponent(localizationEntity.Id, localizationEntity.Name));

    // saving category entity to database
    await this.persistEntityPipeline.Run(new PersistEntityArgument(categoryEntity), context);
}
```

Comment: This answer is no longer valid as of XC 9.2, Please see @Hao Liu's answer below for the correct approach moving forwards

Answer (score 5):

There are some changes in Experience Commerce 9.2, copied below from one of the related support ticket:

In previous versions of Sitecore Commerce, the LocalizedEntityComponent was used to know which localization entity was related to an entity. In 9.2 the localization entity ID was changed to a composition of the commerce entity ID for a localization entity and the entity ID, e.g. The localization entity ID for an entity with ID 'Entity-SellableItem-12345' would then be 'Entity-LocalizationEntity-12345'. This then makes the LocalizationEntityComponent obsolete, as the localization entity can be inferred from the entity ID.

To explain with the above linked stackexchange post, the following:

> LocalizationEntity localizationEntity = await
> this.localizeEntityPropertyCommand.GetLocalizationEntity(context.CommerceContext,
> categoryEntity);

now generates the localizationEntity with an ID following the above mentioned new format.
This then renders the following code not necessary:

// this is needed if initial category didn't have
LocalizedEntityComponent to link category with localization entity

> if
> (!categoryEntity.HasComponent()) {
> categoryEntity.SetComponent(new
> LocalizedEntityComponent(localizationEntity.Id,
> localizationEntity.Name)); // saving category entity to database await
> this.persistEntityPipeline.Run(new
> PersistEntityArgument(categoryEntity), context); }